# Should Supplier be used to supply File Stream?

Tags: java, java-stream, try-with-resources

I needed to supply a `Stream` of a file more than once so that different operations could be executed upon it at different times, I used the following Supplier:

```
Supplier<Stream<String>> linesSupplier = () -> {
    try
    {
        return Files.lines(Paths.get(file.toURI()));
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        log.error("Error while supplying file " + file.getName(), e);
    }
    return null;
};
```

Unfortunately, it leads to a [file handle leak](https://area-51.blog/2015/04/10/java-8-running-out-of-file-handles-on-linux/), so I tried to use a try-with-resource as suggested.

```
Supplier<Stream<String>> linesSupplier = () -> {
    try(Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(Paths.get(file.toURI())))
    {
        return lines;
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        log.error("Error while supplying file " + file.getName(), e);
    }
    return null;
};
```

But now the first time I use `linesSupplier.get()`, I get a [`java.lang.IllegalStateException`](https://www.mkyong.com/java8/java-stream-has-already-been-operated-upon-or-closed/).

Is it a sign that I should try to actively avoid `Supplier`, whatever the circumstances?

Comment: I'm not sure this has anything to do with `Supplier`s - your try-with-resources is closing the stream before it's returned.

Comment: The code using the supplier would be responsible for closing the stream.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course not - you should use a `Supplier` when you need to. The problem here is that `Stream` class implements `AutoCloseable` and your `try-with-resource` is calling it's `close` method after it ends.

As such, one should either make the `Supplier` responsible of closing the `Stream` by moving the `try-with-resource` or one could return something else as a `Stream`, for example, a `List<String>`.

Comment: So it is just an issue of the `Supplier` not being the right tool in my case.

Comment: @Eldros depending on what you do, you might return a `List<String>` from that supplier for example

Comment: Took the liberty to add this new information to the answer so it would be complete.